# how to hide USE FALLBACK in Plugin.Fingerprint dialogue

Tags: xamarin.forms, fingerprint

i have implemented finger-touch login using  Plugin.Fingerprint Pluginin my xamarin application.

i dont want to show USE FALLBACK option in dialogue.

i have tried this way to hide it

```
 var config = new AuthenticationRequestConfiguration("pput your finger to authenticate!")
                {
                    FallbackTitle = string.Empty
                };

                var auth = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync(config);
```

but it is still showing.

anyone have idea how can i hide that?

please help .

Comment: Since this plugin is an open source project, check the source code. If it is not possible to achieve what you want then contribute and add a missing feature.

Comment: @EvZ thnkx eve.btw do u know what this "USE FALLBACK" means in this context? for what it is used?

Comment: Its used for alternative auth method, read the README.md everything is written there.

Answer (score 1):

On android platform, if you want to disable it, you can inherit from FingerprintDialogFragment and override OnCreateView.

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.fingerprint_btnFallback).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    return view;
}
```

In your MainApplication class, override OnCreate

```
public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
            //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!

            CrossFingerprint.SetCurrentActivityResolver(() => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity);

            CrossFingerprint.SetDialogFragmentType<MyCustomDialogFragment>();
        }
```